# Read url data and redirect in route file using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I will get below mentioned url from 3rd party server..

> http://localhost/timespotproject/public/guestacc/chk/defaults/?ids=123e34&ab=00tt&temp=1245678&url=http://test.com%2f&sid=Free+term

When I get this url I have used below mentioned code in routes.php file

```
Route::get('guestacc/scheck/default/{data}','User@guestcheck');
```

but it's not redirected.
  I have to redirect my action to "User@guestcheck" when i receive above mentioned url...
    also if I receive any other url without http://localhost/timespotproject/public/guestacc

> (ie     http://localhost/timespotproject/public/login)

also i have to redirect User@guestcheck

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `data` chunk like:

> http://localhost/timespotproject/public/guestacc/chk/defaults/**somedata**?ids=123e34&ab=00tt&temp=1245678&url=http://test.com%2f&sid=Free+term

or to get rid of it and remove it form the route if you are just going to use the get params as follows:

```
Route::get('guestacc/scheck/defaults','User@guestcheck');
```

Comment: i can't change this url format.. it was redirected from another server

Comment: this is constant format from 3rd party  "guestacc/chk/defaults/?ids=123e34&ab=00tt&temp=1245678&url=http://test.com%2f&sid=Free+term"

Comment: i other words change your route to this one:
    Route::get('guestacc/scheck/defaults','User@guestcheck');

Comment: if i give url === http://localhost/timespotproject/public/guestacc/chk/defaults     and  in route file ===Route::get('guestacc/scheck/defaults','User@guestcheck');  then it works

Comment: if i give url === http://localhost/timespotproject/public/guestacc/chk/defaults/?ids=123e34&ab=00tt&temp=1245678&url=http://test.com%2f&sid=Free+term   and    in route file === Route::get('guestacc/scheck/defaults','User@guestcheck');  then it's not working..

Comment: try to change your route to this Route::get('guestacc/scheck/defaults/','User@guestcheck');

Comment: but its not working here.. if i avoid using /? in url then its working.. only problem is /? in the url (.....default/?id=.......)

Comment: what do you mean by "not working" do you have any errors present??

Comment: otherwise if i receive any other url from 3rd party server like   http://localhost/timespotproject/public/wasteacc/chk/defaults (except /adminacc/chk/defaults or /guestacc/chk/defaults) then i want to redirect to User@guestcheck